# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not construct instance of helper class class

Tags: ormlite, android-6.0-marshmallow

I used `**ormlite greendao**` for my Android application, everything works well until my android phone upgrade to Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) these days.

The problem happens at this line in my code:

```
  private DatabaseHelper getHelper() {
        if (mHelper == null)
            mHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(mContext, DatabaseHelper.class);// Error raise here
        return mHelper;
    }
```

And I catch out this causes the issue:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException:
>   java.lang.Class is not
>   accessible from
>   java.lang.Class

I have researched on the internet but couldn't figure out.
**It only happens in Android 6.**

**Update**

Cause:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class<com.mypackage.DatabaseHelper> is not accessible from java.lang.Class<com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OpenHelperManager>
```

Comment: Please post the full exception.  I suspect there is a caused by that explains the problem.

Comment: Please see my update above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by myself
As the cause problem above I changed class access level of

> com.mypackage.DatabaseHelper

into public class.